# Filter XML using XSLT based on a child Node

Tags: xml, xslt, logic, xslt-1.0

I have the XML below and I would like to filter the XML using XSLT to seprate CompanyType based on IsBusiness

```
   <CompanyTypes>
            <CompanyType>
               <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
               <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
               <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
               <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
            </CompanyType>
            <CompanyType>
               <CompanyTypeID>2</CompanyTypeID>
               <CompanyTypeName>Proprietorship</CompanyTypeName>
               <CompanyTypeDesc>Proprietorship</CompanyTypeDesc>
               <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
            </CompanyType>
            <CompanyType>
               <CompanyTypeID>3</CompanyTypeID>
               <CompanyTypeName>Trust Irrevocable</CompanyTypeName>
               <CompanyTypeDesc>Irrevocable Trust</CompanyTypeDesc>
               <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
            </CompanyType>
            <CompanyType>
               <CompanyTypeID>4</CompanyTypeID>
               <CompanyTypeName>Trust Revocable</CompanyTypeName>
               <CompanyTypeDesc>Revocable Trust</CompanyTypeDesc>
               <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
            </CompanyType>
            <CompanyType>
               <CompanyTypeID>5</CompanyTypeID>
               <CompanyTypeName>Association</CompanyTypeName>
               <CompanyTypeDesc>Association</CompanyTypeDesc>
               <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
            </CompanyType>
          </CompanyTypes>
```

I would like to get all the IsBusiness = N in

```
<CompanyTypesIndividual>
  <CompanyType>
   <CompanyTypeID>3</CompanyTypeID>
   <CompanyTypeName>Trust Irrevocable</CompanyTypeName>
   <CompanyTypeDesc>Irrevocable Trust</CompanyTypeDesc>
   <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
  </CompanyType>
 <CompanyType>
   <CompanyTypeID>4</CompanyTypeID>
   <CompanyTypeName>Trust Revocable</CompanyTypeName>
   <CompanyTypeDesc>Revocable Trust</CompanyTypeDesc>
   <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
  </CompanyType>
</CompanyTypesIndividual>
```

and ISBusiness = Y

```
<CompanyTypesBusiness>
  <CompanyType>
   <CompanyTypeID>3</CompanyTypeID>
   <CompanyTypeName>Trust Irrevocable</CompanyTypeName>
   <CompanyTypeDesc>Irrevocable Trust</CompanyTypeDesc>
   <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
  </CompanyType>
<CompanyType>
   <CompanyTypeID>3</CompanyTypeID>
   <CompanyTypeName>Trust Irrevocable</CompanyTypeName>
   <CompanyTypeDesc>Irrevocable Trust</CompanyTypeDesc>
   <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
  </CompanyType>
</CompanyTypesBusiness>
```

Really appreciate your feedback

Comment: Do you mean you want to have two output documents as a result of a single transformation? That's not possible in XSLT 1.0 (unless your processor supports an extension to enable such thing).

Comment: Hi Michael, 

I don't need two documents as an ouput, I need to map the result as shown in my example into two new nodes. <CompanyTypesBusiness> and <CompanyTypesIndividual> based on the IsBusiness Value

Comment: That should be very easy. For example, you could use `xsl:copy-of` with the expression suggested by Lingamurthy CS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CompanyTypesIndividual>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CompanyTypes/CompanyType[IsBusiness='N']"/>
    </CompanyTypesIndividual>
    <CompanyTypesBusiness>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CompanyTypes/CompanyType[IsBusiness='Y']"/>
    </CompanyTypesBusiness>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your input XML produces the desired output.
The template matching the XML root applies templates to all `CompanyTypes` where `IsBusiness='N'` wrapped in a `<CompanyTypesIndividual>` group and then to all `CompanyTypes` where `IsBusiness='Y'` wrapped in a `<CompanyTypesBusiness>` group. The applied `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` just copies the nodes and attributes.
For convenience I've saved the transformation [here](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiKa)

**Update:** As pointed out by michael.hor257k as comment, this result is not valid XML. To have valid XML, the result file has to start and end with the same element, e.g. with this adjustment:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <CompanyTypes>
      <CompanyTypesIndividual>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CompanyTypes/CompanyType[IsBusiness='N']"/>
      </CompanyTypesIndividual>
      <CompanyTypesBusiness>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CompanyTypes/CompanyType[IsBusiness='Y']"/>
      </CompanyTypesBusiness>
    <CompanyTypes>
</xsl:template>
```

In addition, you may want to either remove `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` or change it to `omit-xml-declaration="no"` to keep the XML declaration in the output XML.

Comment: Your result is not XML.

Comment: Really appreciate it matthias_h

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for mentioning, updated in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't correlate your input with the expected outputs.
The xpath to get `CompanyType` with IsBusiness = 'N' would be:

```
/CompanyTypes/CompanyType[IsBusiness = 'N']
```

Comment: I can't use XPath. When I use XPath its returning the first instance only, because the application is using Xpath version 1.0.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @SherifAbdelzaher even in version 1.0 the xpath to select all would be the one I've mentioned, but the way you use it is that matters. If you use `xsl:copy-of`, `xsl:for-each`, or `xsl:apply-templates` this would work fine, but when `xsl:value-of` is used only first value is presented.